# How to test for a reference cycle caused by saved exception?

Tags: python, garbage-collection

I'm talking about this problem: https://bugs.python.org/issue36820.

Small summary:

Saving an exception causes a cyclic reference, because the exception's data include a traceback containing the stack frame with the variable where the exception was saved.

```
try:
    1/0
except Exception as e:
    ee = e
```

The code is not broken, beacuse Python will eventually free the memory with its garbage collector. But the whole sitation can be avoided:

```
try:
    1/0
except Exception as e:
    ee = e
    ...
    ...
finally:
    ee = None
```

---

In the linked bpo-36820 there is a demonstration with a weak reference kept alive.

My question is if there exist a test that does not need to edit the function itself.
Something like

- run the tested function
- check if a new cycle was created

Can the `gc` module do that?

Comment: with gc.set_threshold(1) right a start of your script sets every cycle is removed instantly but beware that will come at a high cost. Instead of 1 even values up to 47 worked. The point of GC is to detect circles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, using the `gc` module, we can check whether there are (new) exceptions that are only referred to by a traceback frame.

In practice, iterating `gc` objects creates an additional referrer (can't use `WeakSet` as built-in exceptions don't support weakref), so we check that there are two referrers — the frame and the additional referrer.

```py
def get_exception_ids_with_reference_cycle(exclude_ids=None):
    import gc
    import types
    exclude_ids = () if exclude_ids is None else exclude_ids
    exceptions = [
        o for o in gc.get_objects(generation=0)
        if isinstance(o, Exception) and id(o) not in exclude_ids
    ]
    exception_ids = [
        id(e) for e in exceptions
        if len(gc.get_referrers(e)) == 2 and all(
            isinstance(r, types.FrameType) or r is exceptions
            for r in gc.get_referrers(e)
        )
    ]
    return exception_ids
```

Usage:

```py
exception_ids = get_exception_ids_with_reference_cycle()
x()
print(bool(get_exception_ids_with_reference_cycle(exclude_ids=exception_ids)))
```

Alternative usage:

```py
@contextlib.contextmanager
def make_helper():
    exception_ids = get_exception_ids_with_reference_cycle()
    yield lambda: bool(get_exception_ids_with_reference_cycle(exclude_ids=exception_ids))


with make_helper() as get_true_if_reference_cycle_was_created:
    x()
    print(get_true_if_reference_cycle_was_created())
```

Answer (score -1):

I believe you can use the gc module to do something like this.

```
import gc

# First, enable garbage collection
gc.enable()

# Save an exception to a variable
exception = Exception('test exception')

# Check for objects that are no longer being referenced by the program
if gc.garbage:
  # Print the objects that are causing the cycle
  print(gc.garbage)

  # Use the gc.get_referrers method to find out what objects
  # are causing the cycle
  for obj in gc.garbage:
    print(gc.get_referrers(obj))

  # Modify your code to break the cycle
  # (This will depend on your specific code and the objects
  # involved in the cycle)
```

Comment: How can I test my existing code with this? I have a function with some non-trivial exception handling. I can run the function in a way that the exception will be thrown. How do I write a test to be sure it does not create a reference cycle?